# Oracle XE: Transfer Database from Linux to Windows

Tags: backup, oracle-10g, restore, oracle-xe

our professor gave us a linux VM with a Oracle XE 11g Database.

I want to transfer this Database to my Windows installation because I dont't want to boot up the VM for every exercise.
Everything should be transferred. Users, Permissions, Procedures, Tables, Data, and so on.

How can I do this.

I already tried to use the "Backup Database" and "Restore Database" buttons but I don't know where the backup is placed and where I have to put the backup files on my windows machine.

Thanks...

Comment: Booting up a VM doesn't cost too much...  Why do you want to avoid it?  Furthermore, the versions indicated don't match.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this with a full export and import of the database.

- Run a full export of the database on the linux VM
- Copy the dump file to your Windows machine
- Do a full import to the database on the Windows machine.

I believe Oracle reccomends the use of Oracle Data Pump:  `expdp` and `impdp` on Oracle 11g and up, rather than the traditional `imp` and `exp` tools.

Oracle Data Pump is well documented: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/part_dp.htm